# VirtualBox Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I haven't used my Windows VM in about a week or so, the only thing I can think of that I've done within that week that may have caused this is cleared out my `~/.cache`.

Anyway, now when I try and launch VirtualBox I get the following error:

> VirtualBox - Critical Error
>
> Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
>
> The application will now terminate.
>
> Document is empty.
>
> Location: '/home/kalenpw/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.
>
> /build/virtualbox-VDAABr/virtualbox-4.3.36-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[536] (nsresult VirtualBox::init()).

sure enough, ~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml is in fact empty, the only issue is I can't figure out what I need that file to be in order for virtual box to work. I've googled the error and everything says I need to change permissions of VirtualBox.xml, but I've already verified my user has permissions. VirtualBox will run if I do `sudo virtualbox` so clearly I've messed something up with that file I am just not sure what. Thanks.

Comment: @Christopher ah, good call didn't think of that. I did in fact have `VirtualBox.xml-prev` and copying the contents of that into `VirtualBox.xml` resolved the issue. If you post this as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look to see if you have an automatic backup of that file, `VirtualBox.xml-prev`. If so, use that file to try to get VirtualBox happy again.

```
cat VirtualBox.xml-prev > VirtualBox.xml
```

Or

```
rm VirtualBox.xml && cp VirtualBox.xml-prev VirtualBox.xml
```

Or maybe find the original in a recent backup.

Comment: Thanks!  This same strategy worked for me on windows as well.

Comment: After I removed VirtualBox.xml-prev and VirtualBox.xml Virtualbox started working again :) tks

Comment: @Memonic That way, you loose all your non-default settings I believe. Didn't the accepted anwer work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too after deleting all the files/folders in Downloads to free space on my hard drive. After then, when I try to launch VirtualBox again, I get the same thing.
I was trying to fix it by using the VirtualBox installer and choosing the option repair. This did nothing at all.
I removed VirtualBox then reinstalled it, but it didn't work.
NOTE:
The actual error when I deleted everything in Downloads is a failure in VirtualBox.xml - Well that happened first, the repair made the VirtualBox.xml empty, not files/folders.